# Been trying to create a simple login form using SQLite

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, windows-forms-designer

Been trying to create a simple login form using SQLite but when i run the program it keeps bringing me an error on the da.Fill(dt);

```
if (txtUserN.Text.Trim() == "" && txtPass.Text.Trim() == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("fucken");
            }
            else
            {
                string query = "SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE User Name= @username AND Password = @password";
                SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=C:\Users\Benjamin\OneDrive\Documents\School Shit\Assignments\ass\chan chan chan\chan chan chan\bin\ddoocp.db");
                conn.Open();
                SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(query, conn);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User Name", txtUserN.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtPass.Text);
                SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);

                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Login Successful");
                }
```

System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException: 'SQL logic error
near "Name": syntax error'

Comment: Here's your problem right there: `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User Name", txtUserN.Text);`. You can't have a space in the parameter name.

Comment: When asking question about SQL it is very useful to post also the database schema otherwise we are just guessing what the query is running on.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is invalid:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE User Name= @username AND Password = @password
                              ^^^^^^^^^
```

You have 2 tokens here but you can only have one. You need to replace that with the name of the column you're trying to filter on.